# How to NULL the repeating column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Below is the result of query that i get after applying couple of joins.

[image]

I want to show first of value of VendorName column and rest as NULL for every similar value of Exp1 column.

for ex:

```
2011   Air Canada    9
2012   NULL          9
2016   NULL          9
```

and so on...

the query i used to generate result is:

```
SELECT     d.ForecastAccountID, d.Portfolio, d.Name, d.AccountNumber, d.AccountName, d.CashGAAP, d.OriginalDate, d.Amount, d.Grouping, d.TheDate, d.CashGAAPYear, 
                      a.VendorName, a.ForecastAccountID AS Expr1
FROM         (SELECT     Forecast_Account.ForecastAccountID, Portfolio.LegalEntityName AS Portfolio, Forecast.Name, Forecast_Account.AccountNumber, CoA.AccountName, 
                                              Forecast_Data.CashGAAP, Forecast_Data.TheDate AS OriginalDate, SUM(Forecast_Data.Amount) AS Amount, Attribute_Set.AttributeSetName AS Grouping, 
                                              DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, Forecast_Data.TheDate), 0) AS TheDate, YEAR(Forecast_Data.TheDate) AS CashGAAPYear
                       FROM          Portfolio INNER JOIN
                                              Forecast ON Portfolio.PortfolioID = Forecast.PortfolioID INNER JOIN
                                              Forecast_Account ON Forecast.ForecastID = Forecast_Account.ForecastID INNER JOIN
                                              Forecast_Data ON Forecast_Account.ForecastAccountID = Forecast_Data.ForecastAccountID INNER JOIN
                                              CoA ON CoA.AccountNumber = Forecast_Account.AccountNumber INNER JOIN
                                              Attribute_Set ON Forecast_Account.AttributeSetID = Attribute_Set.AttributeSetID
                       GROUP BY Forecast_Account.ForecastAccountID, Portfolio.LegalEntityName, Forecast.Name, Forecast_Account.AccountNumber, CoA.AccountName, 
                                              Forecast_Data.CashGAAP, Forecast_Data.TheDate, Attribute_Set.AttributeSetName) AS d LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          (SELECT     Vendor.VendorName, Forecast_Attribute.ForecastAccountID
                            FROM          Forecast_Attribute INNER JOIN
                                                   Vendor ON Forecast_Attribute.Value = Vendor.VendorName
                            GROUP BY Forecast_Attribute.ForecastAccountID, Vendor.VendorName) AS a ON d.ForecastAccountID = a.ForecastAccountID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like This

```
Select CashGAApYear,
       Case
            when Row > 1 then Null
            else VendorName end AS VendorName,
       Exp1 
From
(
   SELECT CashGAApYear, 
          VendorName,
          Exp1,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VendorName,CashGAApYear  ORDER BY VendorName  ASC) AS Row
    from TableName
)  AS T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c1,
CASE rn
WHEN 1 THEN c2
ELSE NULL
END
,c3 from 
(
select Row_number() over (order by c1 asc ) as rn ,c1,c2,c3 from mytable 
)ttable
```